Can the exclusion restriction in instrumental variable estimation be expressed as $\mathrm{cov}(Z, Y | X) = 0$?
In instrumental variable (IV) estimation of the regression model $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$, where $Y$ is the outcome, $X$ is an endogenous independent variable, $\epsilon$ is the error term, and $Z$ is an exogenous instrument, the relevance criterion can be expressed as $\mathrm{cov}(Z, X) \ne 0$, and the exogeneity criterion as $\mathrm{cov}(Z, \epsilon) = 0$.
However, I have not encountered a similar expression for the exclusion restriction. As far as I understand, the exclusion restriction means that the instrument $Z$ only affects $Y$ through its effect on $X$. Does this imply that the covariance between $Z$ and $Y$ should be $0$, once controlled for $X$, i.e. $\mathrm{cov}(Z, Y | X) = 0$?

Note that your expressions are assuming simple linear relationships between the involved variables. More broadly speaking, relevance and exclusion restriction conditions are statements about (conditional) independence, and it is well known that uncorrelatedness does not imply independence.

Furthermore, if you are discussing the classic example of a causal instrument, then your proposed expression does not capture the full picture, as it makes no distinction to whether $X$ needs to be a mediator.

What (more general) expression would then capture the full picture?

Any statistical expression cannot do, as you need to encode causal structural assumptions somehow. Perhaps one could do with Pearl's do operator.

$cov(Z,\epsilon)=0$ includes the exclusion restriction. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461729/instrumental-variables-unconfoundness-vs-exclusion-restriction/584711#584711

@Jonathan That is not true in general, your own cited response has a counterexample. Assume that the effect of $Z$ on $Y$ is 0 (the $\gamma$ red arrow in your response). Then, by the open path $Z \leftarrow Q \rightarrow Y$, $\operatorname{Cov}(Z, \epsilon) \neq 0$ in general. However, exclusion restriction is satisfied.

Perhaps I was a bit too concise, but I didn’t say that it implies the exclusion restriction. The assumption that $cov(Z,\epsilon)=0$ includes both the exclusion restriction and the assumption that the instrument is exogenous.

I will provide an answer for the linear model $ Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon $ with another expression for the exclusion restriction than the one you propose.
The theoretical analogue (and probability limit) of $\hat{\beta}_{IV}$ is
$$ \frac{Cov(Z,Y)}{Cov(Z,X)} = \frac{\beta Cov(Z,X) + Cov(Z,\epsilon)}{Cov(Z,X)} $$
From this, we see that $Cov(Z,X) \neq 0$ and $Cov(Z,\epsilon)=0$ are sufficient for
$$\frac{Cov(Z,Y)}{Cov(Z,X)} = \beta $$
There is no need for further assumptions than those you call the relevance criterion and the exogeneity criterion. However, the exogeneity criterion can be split into two different assumptions. If we write
$$ \epsilon = \gamma Z + u $$
$$ Cov(Z,\epsilon) = \gamma Var(Z) + Cov(Z,u)$$
we can state the  exclusion restriction as $\gamma = 0$. The second assumption we make is that the effect of $Z$ on $Y$ is unconfounded, $Cov(Z,u)=0$; i.e., there are no variables that explain both $Z$ and $Y$. Together, the exclusion restriction and the unconfoundedness assumption imply $Cov(Z,\epsilon)=0$.

Regarding your suggestion $Cov(Z,Y|X) = 0$, my tentative answer would be no. If we assume $Cov(Z,\epsilon)=0$, then it becomes redundant. If we don't, we can substitute for $Y$ to get
$Cov(Z,Y|X) = Cov(Z,\alpha + \beta X + \epsilon|X) = Cov(Z,\epsilon|X)$
but from here, we cannot get any further in separating the exclusion restriction from unconfoundedness without defining $\epsilon = \gamma Z + u$ and then $\gamma = 0$ is the most straightforward (if not the only) way of stating the exclusion restriction.

I'm not sure I can agree with this answer. The statement $\epsilon=\gamma Z + u$ is an assumption, not a mathematical result. If the reality were that $\epsilon=\gamma'Z^2+u$ then, assuming $\epsilon=\gamma Z+x$, you might estimate $\gamma$ to be zero, even though the exclusion restriction is violated.
I have the impression that the confusion behind the question is a conflation of linear independence and probabilistic independence - and this answer seems to fall into the same trap. Perhaps I'm overlooking something - if so, let me know!

To give an example of the difference I'm pointing out: Take your model of $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$. A regression model will recover $\beta$ in unbiased fashion if $\operatorname{Cov}(X, \epsilon) = 0$. However $\operatorname{Cov}(X, \epsilon)$ may be zero, despite confounding by $C$, for example if $X = C+\varepsilon$ and $\epsilon = C^2 + u$. It is the same here: linear IV regression may work despite a violation of the exclusion restriction.
So the exclusion restriction as stated here works for linear regression, but it does not generally ensure $Z$ only causes $Y$ via $X$.

Yes, I’m assuming linear effects. Note that I’m also assuming that $\gamma$ cannot be estimated. Your point is very interesting. I will think about it more and edit to clarify when on my computer rather than phone. My impression was that OP was also  assuming linear effects and was asking about how to express the exclusion restriction in this context.

Perhaps one thing to note here is that yours and OPs formulation of the exclusion restriction require extending the assumption of linear effects to all causal relationships beyond $X\to Y$ (I have added a nonlinear counterexample to my answer). I think this is a subtle point that often isn't stated very explicitly in the context of linear IV regression. For a general formulation probabilistic independence is needed, the Wikipedia article uses a graphical way of expressing the same thing.

The first comment says it already, but let me try to flesh it out a bit. $\text{Cov}(Z,Y\mid X)=0$ is not a statement about probabilistic independence, but rather about linear independence. For probabilistic independence, you'd have to show that $P(Z\mid X)\times P(Y\mid X) = P(Z,Y\mid X)$, which is not guaranteed by $\text{Cov}(Z,Y\mid X)=0$. For example: given $X$, there may well be a quadratic relationship between $Y$ and $Z$ that still results in $\text{Cov}(Z,Y\mid X)=0$.
Edit: Counterexample
For an illustration of the difference and a counterexample to $\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z\mid X)=0$ being a sufficient criterion for the exclusion restriction (as well as to the other answer), consider the following set-up where the "IV" is actually a confounder of $X$ and $Y$, but the condition is still met. This goes to show that the criterion $\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z\mid X)=0$ may be sufficient for a linear model to recover the correct parameter, but it is not sufficient as a criterion for the exclusion restriction in generality, i.e. the instrumental variable causing $Y$ only through $X$.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as LR
# setup
n = 10000000
IV = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)# the "IV" is actually a confounder!!!
X = IV + np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
Y = IV**2 + X + np.random.normal(0, 1, n)# exclusion restriction violated
# estimation
X_hat = LR().fit(IV.reshape(-1, 1), X).predict(IV.reshape(-1, 1))
print('Correct coef 1:',LR().fit(X_hat.reshape(-1, 1), Y).coef_)# correct result
# Cov(X, Y | IV) = 0
E_YgX = LR().fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), Y).predict(X.reshape(-1, 1))
E_IVgX = LR().fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), IV).predict(X.reshape(-1, 1))
conditional_covariance = np.mean((Y - E_YgX) * (IV - E_IVgX))
print("Cov(X,Y|IX) is 0:",conditional_covariance)# despite violation


Are you sure that it has only to do with independent vs uncorrelated? I suspect that it might not be possible because it is a causal concept and correlation does not capture the direction of causality, linear or not.

In the IV setup $Z$ causes $Y$ through $X$ by the relevance criterion. So if the system is to be a DAG, the exclusion restriction can be violated by $Z$ causing $Y$ in another way, or by there being a confounder. Under the causal Markov and faithfulness conditions, either would be equivalent to conditional dependence given $X$. So under these assumptions, showing conditional independence should do.

Would $\mathbb{E}[Z X] \ne 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z \epsilon] = 0$ then be more generalised expressions (beyond linear relationships) for the relevance and exogeneity criteria, respectively?

I'd say there is the same problem: $E[ZX]\neq0$ is a particular type of dependence, and $E[Z\epsilon]=0$ doesn't guarantee independence.
